# Can't pass an assert test for a Recursion Function

Tags: javascript, recursion, mocha.js

```
var compareStr = function(str1, str2) {

    if (str1.slice(1) !== str2.slice(1)) {
        return false;
    } 

    if (str1.slice(1) === '' && str2.slice(1) === '') {
        return true;
    } 

     return compareStr(str1.slice(1), str2.slice(1));
}
```

I'm making a compare string function between two string arguments using recursion. I am testing my function against a variety of mocha tests. I can't pass this one in particular.

```
AssertionError: expected 1 to be above 1
```

which points to this code:

```
  it('should use recursion by calling self', function() {
    compareStr('house', 'houses');
    expect(compareStr.callCount).to.be.above(1);
  });
```

Now what I think is happening is that if `str1` and `str2` are not equal from the first element then my function returns false. Which in my opinion is a good edge case to have since there's no point in executing the function after that. Is this assert test looking for a result of `false` after it's passed a recursion itself at least once? Meaning that the recursion needs to occur AT least once for this to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the test is expecting you to write a function that compares the strings character-by-character, in which case you need to get to the final `s` of `houses` for recursion to finish:

```js
var compareStr = function(str1, str2) {
    console.log('compareStr called');
    return str1.length <= 1 || str2.length <= 1
      ? str1 === str2
      : compareStr(str1.slice(1), str2.slice(1));
};

console.log(compareStr('house', 'houses'));
```

Comment: Ah I see. This code does work - question. Is my current code valid to test for this? Seems to pass every string combination I throw at it. Just made more sense to me to see if comparing them did NOT match.

Comment: No, your current code doesn't check the first characters of the initial call. `compareStr('foo', 'boo')`

Comment: It's a *really* strange problem to solve using recursion, since you can just do `return str1 === str2`. I think it'd be good for the maintainers to swap this out with another question, it's odd and the test requirement is confusing (as you encountered).

Comment: Doh. I am just making all kinds of beginner mistakes. Changing the the compare to `if (str.slice(0,1) !== str.slice(0,1))` did the trick. Back to basics for me if I'm misusing slice like this. Yes, definitely. Most of these problems have more straight forward answers to them, but this is just for the sake of practicing recursion to practice. Basically, I'm just working through Recursion prompts here if anyone is interested: https://github.com/JS-Challenges/recursion-prompts. Thanks again @CertainPerformance!